# How to add the Postgresql jdbc driver 9.2-1003-jdbc3 with Maven?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, postgresql-9.2

I have found the Postgresql JDBC4 driver here : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1003-jdbc4.

But I can't seem to find the **9.2-1003-jdbc3**.

Do you know of an online maven repository that store it ?

**Nota:**
I don't want to download the jar manually and then add it to my local maven repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `jdbc3` version of the 9.2-1003 `postgresql` artifact hasn't been published to Central. You'll need to stick with the most recent release that has been published ([9.1-901.jdbc3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|postgresql|postgresql|9.1-901.jdbc3|jar)), switch to `jdbc4` (which is recommended if you're using Java 1.6 or later), or [download from `postgresql.org`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) and install to your own repository.

Unless you have very specific requirements to use a [long-unsupported JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-137837.html), moving to the `jdbc4` driver is your best option.

Comment: I asked on the pgsql-jdbc list to add the driver on the Maven Central and they did it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you will have to install your driver's jar as dependency in your local repository(mvn install) and than you will be able to add this dependency to any project using maven's pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add dependency to your POM file. The JAR will be downloaded automatically and placed in your local Maven's repository.

At least as for me this dependency worked and driver was added to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```